# Count number of filtered data is not working in my query

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views

> I want to count the filtered data and show it via Alert, but in my
> code count is not working. I also filter the date One day ahead the
> current date. How to work this?

```
def repairList(request):
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
        dl1 = Repair.objects.filter(Deadline__date = datetime.datetime.today() + timedelta(days=1)).annotate(Count("id"))
    
    print(dl1)
    
    return render(request,'repair/repair_list.html',{'Title':'Repair List', 'dl1':dl1})
```

> **print output**

```
<QuerySet [<Repair: VRR2020-000001>]>
```

Comment: `print(dl1[0].count_id)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably it'll be easier to use aggregation (if you don't need original queryset, just append aggregation part):

```
dl1 = Repair.objects.filter(Deadline__date = datetime.datetime.today() + timedelta(days=1))
dl1_count = dl1.aggregate(counted=Count('id'))['counted']  # number of records
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just count filtered `Repair` records you can use:

```
dl1_count = Repair.objects.filter(Deadline__date = datetime.datetime.today() + timedelta(days=1)).count()
print(dl1_count)
```

And printing the code of yours (I mean the line `dl1 = Repair.objects.filter(Deadline__date = datetime.datetime.today() + timedelta(days=1)).annotate(Count("id"))` and `print(dl1)`) does not show any result for that count because you have printed the queryset object so if you want to use your code you should change it to something like:

```
dl1 = Repair.objects.filter(Deadline__date = datetime.datetime.today() + timedelta(days=1)).annotate(Count("id"))

for obj in dl1:
    print(obj.id__count)
```

because annotate adds that field to objects not to the queryset.